C# The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception
I am experiencing an unhandled exception which, as per my understanding, occurs when a task is cancelled before it is completed. However, in my code, I am not cancelling any tasks. I have added try-catch blocks and multiple handlers, but I am still unable to find the issue. The crash happens randomly and there are no fixed steps leading up to it.
crash happen after 2-3 hrs of running connection properly
Error

Application: AlgoOrderPlacement.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
at SocketIOClient.Transport.HttpTransport+d__13.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
at SocketIOClient.Transport.TransportRouter+d__43.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
at SocketIOClient.Transport.TransportRouter+d__41.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
at SocketIOClient.SocketIO+d__81.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at SocketIOClient.SocketIO+d__81.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
at SocketIOClient.SocketIO+d__105.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()

    namespace AlgoOrderManagement.Helper
    {
        public class OrderSocketConnection
        {
            protected SocketIO Socket { get; set; } = null;
            long lastSocketSequence = 0;
            public Dictionary<string, OrderData> OrderStatusDetails = new Dictionary<string, OrderData>();
            private User currentUser = null;
    
            public delegate void SocketStatus(bool status);
            public event SocketStatus SocketStatusUpdate;
            string URL = string.Empty;
            public void StartSocket(User user, string URL)
            {
                this.currentUser = user;
                this.URL = URL;
                _ = StartSocketAsync();
            }
    
            private async Task StartSocketAsync()
            {
                try
                {
                    if (this.Socket != null)
                    {
                        UnSubscribeToConnectionEvents();
                    }
    
                    if (this.Socket != null)
                    {
                        this.Socket?.DisconnectAsync();
                        this.Socket?.Dispose();
                    }
    
                    this.Socket = new SocketIO(URL, new SocketIOOptions
                    {
                        Query = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "token", currentUser.TOKEN }, { "userID", currentUser.USERID }, { "apiType", "INTERACTIVE" } },
                        EIO = 3,
                        Transport = SocketIOClient.Transport.TransportProtocol.Polling,
                        Path = "/interactive/socket.io"
                    });
    
                    SubscribeToConnectionEvents();
                    FileLogger.logMessage(currentUser.USERNAME + " Before StartSocket");
                    await this.Socket.ConnectAsync();
                    FileLogger.logMessage(currentUser.USERNAME + " After StartSocket");
    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    FileLogger.logMessage("User StartSocket EX = " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
                    await Task.Delay(5000);
                    _ = StartSocketAsync();
                }
            }
    
            private void Socket_OnReconnecting(object sender, int e)
            {
                FileLogger.logMessage(currentUser.USERNAME + " SOCKET SUCCESS= " + e, currentUser.USERNAME);
            }
    
            private void Socket_OnDisconnected(object sender, string e)
            {
                FileLogger.logMessage(currentUser.USERNAME + " SOCKET DIS-CONNECT= " + e, currentUser.USERNAME);
                UpdateUISocketStatus(false);
            }
    
            private void Socket_OnPong(object sender, TimeSpan e)
            {
                
            }
    
            private void Socket_OnPing(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                
            }
    
            private void Socket_OnConnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                FileLogger.logMessage(currentUser.USERNAME + " SOCKET SUCCESS= " + e, currentUser.USERNAME);
            }
    
            private void OrderUpdate(object order)
            {
                try
                {
                    dynamic data = JObject.Parse(order.ToString());
                    if (data != null)
                    {
                        if (data.SequenceNumber.Value > lastSocketSequence)
                        {
                            lastSocketSequence = data.SequenceNumber.Value;
                            OrderData orderData = new OrderData();
                            orderData.orderID = data.AppOrderID;
                            orderData.order_status = data.OrderStatus;
                            orderData.cancelRejectReason = data.CancelRejectReason;
                            orderData.order_execute_price = data.OrderAverageTradedPrice;
                            orderData.quantity = data.CumulativeQuantity;
                            orderData.instrument_token = data.ExchangeInstrumentID;
                            orderData.lastUpdateTime = DateTime.Now;
                            if (OrderStatusDetails.ContainsKey(orderData.orderID))
                            {
                                OrderStatusDetails[orderData.orderID] = orderData;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                OrderStatusDetails.Add(orderData.orderID, orderData);
                            }
                        }
    
                        CheckCancelOrder(data);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    FileLogger.logMessage("OrderUpdate EX = " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace, currentUser.USERNAME);
                }
            }
    
            private void CheckCancelOrder(dynamic data)
            {
                try
                {
                    string orderStatus = data.OrderStatus.ToString();
                    string cancelRejectReason = data.CancelRejectReason.ToString();
                    string orderGeneratedDateTimeAPI = data.LastUpdateDateTimeAPI.ToString();
                    if (orderStatus.ToLower().Equals("cancelled".ToLower()))
                    {
                        TelegramSend.SendError(currentUser.USERNAME + " = Order Cancelled Please Check Once = "
                            + data.CancelRejectReason + Environment.NewLine +
                            "TIME = " + orderGeneratedDateTimeAPI);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
    
                }
            }
    
            private bool SubscribeToConnectionEvents()
            {
                if (this.Socket == null)
                    return false;
    
                this.Socket.On("joined", (data) =>
                {
                    FileLogger.logMessage(" SOCKET JOINED= " + data, currentUser.USERNAME);
                    UpdateUISocketStatus(true);
                });
    
                this.Socket.On("success", (data) =>
                {
                    FileLogger.logMessage(" SOCKET SUCCESS= " + data, currentUser.USERNAME);
                });
    
                this.Socket.On("warning", (data) =>
                {
                    FileLogger.logMessage(" SOCKET WARNING= " + data, currentUser.USERNAME);
                });
    
                this.Socket.On("error", (data) =>
                {
                    FileLogger.logMessage(" SOCKET ERROR= " + data, currentUser.USERNAME);
                    UpdateUISocketStatus(false);
                });
    
                this.Socket.On("logout", (data) =>
                {
                    FileLogger.logMessage(currentUser.USERNAME + " SOCKET LOGOUT= " + data, currentUser.USERNAME);
                    UpdateUISocketStatus(false);
                });
    
                this.Socket.On("order", (order) =>
                {
                    OrderUpdate(order.GetValue<string>());
                    FileLogger.logMessage(currentUser.USERNAME + " SOCKET ORDER = " + order.ToString(), currentUser.USERNAME);
                });
    
                this.Socket.On("trade", (trade) =>
                {
                    OrderUpdate(trade.GetValue<string>());
                    FileLogger.logMessage(currentUser.USERNAME + " SOCKET TRADE = " + trade.ToString(), currentUser.USERNAME);
                });
    
                this.Socket.OnConnected += Socket_OnConnected;
                this.Socket.OnPing += Socket_OnPing;
                this.Socket.OnPong += Socket_OnPong;
                this.Socket.OnDisconnected += Socket_OnDisconnected;
                this.Socket.OnReconnectAttempt += Socket_OnReconnecting;
    
                return true;
            }
    
            private void UnSubscribeToConnectionEvents()
            {
                if (this.Socket != null)
                {
                    this.Socket?.Off("logout");
                    this.Socket?.Off("error");
                    this.Socket?.Off("warning");
                    this.Socket?.Off("success");
                    this.Socket?.Off("joined");
                    this.Socket?.Off("order");
                    this.Socket?.Off("trade");
                    this.Socket.OnConnected -= Socket_OnConnected;
                    this.Socket.OnPing -= Socket_OnPing;
                    this.Socket.OnPong -= Socket_OnPong;
                    this.Socket.OnDisconnected -= Socket_OnDisconnected;
                    this.Socket.OnReconnectAttempt -= Socket_OnReconnecting;
                }
            }
    
            private void UpdateUISocketStatus(bool status)
            {
                try
                {
                    SocketStatusUpdate?.Invoke(status);
                    if (status == false)
                    {
                        TelegramSend.SendError(currentUser.USERNAME + " Socekt Disconnected ");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    FileLogger.logMessage("User UpdateUISocketStatus EX = " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace, currentUser.USERNAME);
                }
            }
        }
    }



Are you using Visual Studio or Rider? If so, in their debugger settings you can set it so that whenever an exception is thrown it will enter stop execution and let you debug the code from there. That should help you better identify what is happening.

An issue is occurring in the production executable only, and not in the debug mode... using visual studio for dev

do you have this log line: FileLogger.logMessage(currentUser.USERNAME + " Before StartSocket"); but not FileLogger.logMessage(currentUser.USERNAME + " After StartSocket"); when that crash happens?

@rene both before after printed in logs
